# Branch.initSession function is not hit

Tags: cordova, branch.io

I am trying to redirect my users to correct page manually if the clicked a branch link to open my app.

I am fairly new to the concept and I don't fully understand the deeplinking, so this maybe wrong way of handling the issue but I am trying it as follows;

I am inside cordova environment, Cordova@7.1.0

installed branch-cordova-sdk 2.6.15

inside deviceready and resume, I initialize branch [docs](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking#initialize-branch)

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    branchInit();
}, false);

document.addEventListener('resume', function() {
    branchInit();
}, false);


function branchInit() {
    // Branch initialization
    console.log("branch init")
    Branch.initSession(function(data) { // this function doesn't get called
        console.log("branch init session:")
        console.log(data)
        if (data['+clicked_branch_link']) {
            $location.path(data['$location_path']); // redirect user to correct path
        }
    }).then(function(q) {
        console.log("initSession success");
        console.log(q);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log("initSession error");
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

And I create quick links from dashboard ([docs](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/guide/#how-to-insert-custom-deep-link-routes-into-a-branch-link)). Send them to my phone(whatsapp) and click the links from whatsapp.

Branch opens my app successfully, but **user doesn't get redirected to the correct page**. And I got following console logs after click,

```
branch init
initSession success
{+clicked_branch_link: false, +is_first_session: false}
```

I think, since clicked_branch_link is false, initSession Callback function doesn't get called.

Comment: There was a bug on the Branch Cordova SDK v2.6.15. Please update your Branch Cordova SDk to 2.6.16. Here are the release notes/comments: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking/issues/384#issuecomment-340621951

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh appearently this update fixed my problem. If you can convert your comment into an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: done. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug on the Branch Cordova SDK v2.6.15 which was causing this issue. Please update your Branch Cordova SDk to 2.6.16.

Here are the release notes/comments: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking/issues/384#issuecomment-340621951